# ASP.Net VB - Passing updated updatepanel values back to another callback function

Tags: asp.net, ajax, callback, linkbutton

I am new to ASP.NET and AJAX so I may be going about things completely the wrong way,

This is all just testing at the moment, I have an updatepanel with an onclick function to access a database and update values. I am trying to update the client id on the page by pressing a linkbutton. This works fine for the first click, but subsequent clicks are obviously still reading the server side data and not the updated clientside data,
I now need to be able to get the updated value of the client id back to my linkbutton click function.

ASPX Code

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:toolkitscriptmanager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:toolkitscriptmanager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton1" EventName="click" /> 
    </Triggers> 

     <ContentTemplate>

<div class="topbox">
   <h3>Client</h3> 


<div style="float:left">

<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="ClientID" Width="150px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

</p>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">next --></asp:LinkButton>
      </ContentTemplate> 
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

ASPX.VB Code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Open_database(1)
End Sub

Public Sub Open_database(e)
    Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection()
    'The SQL Connection
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
    'The SQL Command
    Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader
    'The Local Data Store
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = xxxx
    'Set the Connection String
    SQLConn.Open()
    'Open the connection
    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
    'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
    SQLCmd.CommandText = "Select * from Client where clientid='" & e & "'"
    'Sets the SQL String
    SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    'Gets Data
    While SQLdr.Read()
        TextBox1.Text = (SQLdr("ClientID"))
    End While
    ' Do While SQLdr.NextResult()
    'Move to the Next Record
    SQLdr.Close()
    'Close the SQLDataReader        
    SQLConn.Close()
    'Close the connection
End Sub

Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
    Dim x = TextBox1.Text + 1
    Open_database(x)
End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated,

twun

Comment: so i figured this out using;
`Private Shared globalvar As Integer`
and changed my click event to,

`Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click
        globalvar = globalvar + 1
        Open_database(globalvar)
    End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

"Avoid use of SHARED variable" For Better Programming...

Just Change `Page_Load()` Code to

```
                     If Not IsPostBack Then
                            Open_database(1)
                     End If
```

Using Above Code `Page_Load()` Will Call Open_database(1) Function Only Once And `LinkButton` Will Give Desired Result...